# Multiply / add Google OR Tools IntVar's and Constants in Java

Tags: java, optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I currently started working with Google OR Tools CP-Sat Solver in Java and facing Problems with simple mathematical equations including constants and the OR-Tools internal "IntVar".

A Small Example of my Problem:

```
    // Variables
    IntVar a = model.newIntVar(0, 5, "a");
    IntVar b = model.newIntVar(0, 5, "b");
    int c = 1;

    // Constraint
    model.addEquality(a, a * c); // Cannot apply * with IntVar and int
    model.addEquality(a, a + b); // Cannot Apply + with IntVars
    
    // What I want to achieve
    model.addEquality(a, a * c + b);
```

I'm used to Python where these type - problematic didnt really exist, there a simple `model.Add(a == a * c + b)`
did the job.

Also Or-Tools LinearExpr.sum or LinearExpr.term didnt help me at all.

Has anyone worked with CP-Sat Optimization Problems in Java and knows a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

There are no operator overloading in java.
So you are stuck with the LinearExpr methods.

Comment: As far as i understand im also stuck with LinearExpr because i cant cast a LinearExpr Object into IntVar. With `d = LinearExpr.term(a,c)` I do the multiplying part and end up with a LinearExpr Object wich I cant use in `LinearExpr.sum(d, b)` bc it expects only IntVar Objects.

Comment: so LinearExpr.ScalProd(new IntVar[]{a, b}, new int[]{c, 1}). Clunky, but this is java. I do not want to support nested expressions.

Comment: Thats the way. Thanks a lot :)